# How to require a group of optional parameters when an argument is provided for just one of the parameters?

Tags: typescript, optional-parameters

I have a function with optional parameters like so

```
export const sentryException = (
  error: Error,
  contextLabel?: string,
  contextInfo?: Context,
  specificTags?: SentryTags,
) => {
```

The last 3, as shown, are optional. However, if `contextLabel` is provided, then `contextInfo` must be provided. I would prefer not to have to do

```
if ((contextLabel && !contextInfo) || (contextInfo && !contextLabel)) {
   // throw error
}
```

As you can imagine, this can get pretty messy as the number of required groupings of inputs grows!

Is there any way to require a subset of optional parameters must be passed in the functional call if a specific parameter is provided?

---

**Edit:**
I just wanted to be clear that the `// throw error` comment isn't related to the `error` parameter. I mean that `contextLabel` and `contextInfo` must always both be defined (not `undefined`); otherwise, the function shouldn't be able to be executed.

So for simplicity, let's assume all the types are strings, except for `error`, then valid calls would be:

```
sentryException(err, 'a', 'b')
sentryException(err, 'a', 'b', 'c')
sentryException(err, undefined, undefined, 'c')
sentryException(err)
```

Comment: That `if` condition is a simple XOR, it can be expressed with `if (contextInfo !== contextLabel)`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for a simple set of [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) where you create the specific argument type pairings that you want:

```
function sentryException(
  contextLabel?: undefined,
  contextInfo?: undefined,
  specificTags?: string,
): void

function sentryException(
  contextLabel: string,
  contextInfo: string,
  specificTags?: string,
): void

function sentryException(
  contextLabel?: string,
  contextInfo?: string,
  specificTags?: string,
): void {
  // implementation...
}

// good
sentryException()
sentryException(undefined, undefined, 'tag')
sentryException('a', 'b', 'tag')

// errors
sentryException('a')
sentryException('a', undefined, 'tag')
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.0-dev.20211229#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwKZigJwJ4FEAeEqADrAgBQBQiiECUq+UAMgIYBGqANgPwBcicABNUwGGFRCANNVr1GUAJJhgcfoLAixE6bOTFUEGGIgAVVgHNk65FnEWZASgEA3ODCGVKoSGSRoMHAIiUngwKho6DAU2Ti4BW0x7GUj5JmVVBLswBz0DIxNzKxts3OdENw8vH2gwlHQsPEISPwi5aKZY7hKknJT2hnSVNSze3Jp9Q2MYM0trUeTKcsqhRABvWQB6TcQYAFtiLlQ9htY-ADpLygBfL23ECzg4TwDG4Jaw8kdKV6Dm0IowlE4kkUg0WhB0kQAHIoJZod9fk0Qq1oaxoWDoewMTC4RYEXcdqhMJg4JhkD8Gn8UZ80QSke8AeE6WCgdpQbj4Y4gA)

Comment: The example in the documention is confusing. When I run `console.log(d3)`, even though two values were supplied, it still prints. I see in the IDE that there is an error, but it doesn't keep it from running. This means, in the context of this example, I still have to provide some sort of logic that more or less says "If two arguments are supplied, then call the function while ignoring the second argument".

Comment: Type errors wont stop your code from transpiling to javascript. It will just transpile _with type errors._ My apps at work have a an automated check that looks for type errors, and if there are any then the code will not deploy to the server. If you treat type errors as critical then this is not a problem. And if you want this code to be usable from plain JS, you can either just hope they read the documentation properly, or you could add runtime check that throws on invalid input. But when everything is pure typescript, the type error should be enough to stop from using this in production.